# MaybeT and Transactions in runDb

Tags: haskell, persistent

For my previous question on chaining failures, Michael Snoyman had suggested I use `MaybeT` to run them so if any of them fails, it will just short-circuit to `Nothing`.

I was under the impression `runDb` runs everything in a transaction. So shouldn't a failure at any point in code automatically rollback the transaction?

```
mauth <- runDb $ runMaybeT $ do
            valid    <- MaybeT $ return $ listToMaybe errs 
            uid      <- MaybeT $ insertUnique u 
            vid     <- MaybeT $ getBy $ UniqueField v -- this step fails but previous insert does not roll back
            auth     <- liftIO $ createAuthToken uid
            return auth
```

When I run the above code, the `getBy` fails but user was still inserted. Am I misunderstanding that `runDb` will rollback on a `Nothing` inside `MaybeT`? Do I need to use some other Monad for this to work?

Appreciate your thoughts on how to best rollback on failure.

**Update**: 
This is what I ended up doing per Michael's suggestion.

```
mauth <- runDb $ do
          ma <- runMaybeT $ do
                   valid <- ... 
          case ma of
            Just _ -> return ma
            Nothing -> liftIO $ throwIO MyException
```

Now I need to figure out how to catch this exception nicely outside and return a proper error message back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Returning `Nothing` is not the same thing as a failure. You'd need to throw a runtime exception (via something like `throwIO`) for Persistent to treat it as a rollback situation.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I have updated my question with the snippet that seems to be working.

Comment: Cool. Have a look at `Control.Exception.Lifted` from `lifted-base` for a way forward on catching that exception.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. I am also trying to figure out how to use `EitherT` so I can actually return error messages for each failure, not just my validation errors. This way I can keep my validation code pure and avoid checking for uniqueness within it. I may have a question if I cannot make it work though :)

Comment: In case someone comes here looking for something like this.  @AndrewThaddeusMartin suggested I use `transactionUndo` in `Database.Persist.Sql`  and that makes my code much nicer and not have to deal with Exceptions.