# Catching an Exception from runDb

Tags: haskell, persistent

This is a follow-up to my previous post. [MaybeT and Transactions in runDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310736/maybet-and-transactions-in-rundb/31323697)

I thought this will be a simple thing to do but I have been trying to figure this out for over a day and still haven't made much progress. So thought I will give up and ask!

I just added a `try` function (from `Control.Exception.Lifted`) to my previous code and I couldn't get the code to type check. Variants like `catch` and `handle` had similar issues.

```
eauth <- LiftIO (
           try( runDb $ do
                ma <- runMaybeT $ do
                   valid <- ... 
                case ma of
                  Just a -> return a
                  Nothing -> liftIO $ throwIO MyException
            )  :: IO (Either MyException Auth) 
          )
case eauth of
    Right auth -> return auth
    Left _     -> lift $ left err400 { errBody = "Could not create user"}
```

My `runDb` looks like this (I also tried a variant where I removed `liftIO`):

```
runDb query = do
    pool <- asks getPool
    liftIO $ runSqlPool query pool
```

I get this error:

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader Config IO)
  arising from a use of ‘runDb’
In the expression: runDb
In the first argument of ‘try’, namely
  ‘(runDb
    $ do { ma <- runMaybeT ...
```

I am running inside servant handler and my return type is `AppM Auth` where

```
 type AppM = ReaderT Config (EitherT ServantErr IO)
```

I have tried many combinations of lifting but doesn't seem to be helping. I thought I will take this opportunity to figure out things from scratch and I hit a wall as well. If someone could suggest how you arrived at the answer, it will be super instructive for me.

This has been my thought process:

1. I see `runSqlConn :: MonadBaseControl IO m => SqlPersistT m a -> Connection -> m a`
2. So that seems to imply it will be in the `IO` monad, which means `try` should work
3. I think check the definition of `MonadBaseControl` which has `class MonadBase b m => MonadBaseControl b m | m -> b`. At this point I am confused. This functional dependency logic seems to be suggest type `m` dictates what `b` will be but in the previous one `b` was specified as `IO`.
4. I check `MonadBase` and that did not give me any clue either.
5. I check `SqlPersistT` and got no clues either.
6. I reduced the problem to something very simple like `` result <- liftIO (try (evaluate (5 `div` 0)) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)) `` and that worked. So I was even more confused at this time. Doesn't `runDb` work in `IO` so shouldn't the same thing work for my original code?

I thought I can figure this out by backtracking but it seems like my level of Haskell knowledge is just not sufficient to get at the root of the problem. Appreciate if people can provide step by step pointers as to arrive at the right solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `LiftIO` a typo, should be `liftIO`? Also `try` cannot change the monad it is running in (`runDB` is not returning an `IO` and you are trying to make it return `IO`). In fact it looks like `try` might work just fine against `runDB` itself.

Comment: You should provide a type signature for `runDb`. Both @Guvante's comment and my answer should make it clear that `runDB` does not return an `IO`. Since the exception you are using has only one value, the `Maybe`/`MaybeT` monad is sufficiently powerful for what you are doing. See the last part of my answer. If you still have trouble, you should include the code you elided in the `runMaybeT` block.

Comment: @Guvante, you are right `LiftIO` was a typo and also your observation is correct. I ended up going down the rabbit hole because of my type signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

General type signature for `try`:

```
(MonadBaseControl IO m, Exception e) => m a -> m (Either e a)
```

Specialized type signature for `try` (as it appears in your code):

```
IO Auth -> IO (Either MyException Auth)
```

So, the monadic value that is the argument to `try` has type:

```
IO Auth
```

Everything listed above, you probably already understood. If we look at the type signature for your `runDb`, we get this:

```
runDb :: (MonadReader Config m, MonadIO m) => SqlPersistT m a -> m a
```

I sort of had to guess because you didn't provide a type signature, but that is probably what it is. So now, the problem should be a little clearer. You are trying to use `runDb` to create a monadic value for something that's supposed to be in `IO`. But `IO` doesn't satisfy the `MonadReader Config` instance that you need.

To make the mistake more clear, let's make `runDb` more monomorphic. You could give it this type signature instead:

```
type AppM = ReaderT Config (EitherT ServantErr IO)
runDb :: SqlPersistT AppM a -> AppM a
```

And now if you tried to compile your code, you would get an even better error. Instead of telling you

```
No instance for (Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader Config IO)
```

It would tell you that `IO` doesn't match `AppM` (although it would probably expand the type synonym). Practically, what this means is that you can't get the shared pool of database connections magically out of `IO`. You need the `ReaderT Config` that was passing it around everywhere.

The easiest fix I can think of would be to stop using exceptions where they aren't necessary:

```
mauth <- runDb $ runMaybeT $ do
            ... -- Same stuff you were doing earlier 
case mauth of
    Just auth -> return auth
    Nothing   -> lift $ left err400 { errBody = "Could not create user"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @Andrew. I had posted this on Reddit as well and someone had suggested what you and @Guvante had mentioned as well. The short story is I had provided type signature for `try` to suppress one error message but it lead to more problems later on. Just removing the `liftIO` and using `try` directly works as long as I move the type signature to the case expression. https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3d5kdm/help_with_catching_exceptions/

Comment: @Ecognium That does work, but as I tried to explain in my last code block, your use of `try` is entirely unnecessary. You are converting a `Maybe` to an `Exception`, catching the `Exception` as an `Either`, and then pattern matching to get back to an `Exception`. My suggestion is to just use `MaybeT` for early termination and then pattern matching on the result of that to turn it into an exception. If you put up your the entire contents of your function somewhere (maybe on another question), then I can show you what I mean better.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I am throwing an Exception is that's the only way to 'rollback' the transaction.  I was just using MaybeT before and a `Nothing` value does not rollback so need to `throwIO Exception`.  There are bunch of insert statements in my `MaybeT` which you will not know from my question, of course.

Comment: As an alternative, there is also [transactionUndo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html), which can roll back a transaction without using the special exception-handling behavior. Just in case you ever need it.

Comment: Oh nice. I did not know about that at all. I will try to use it instead of `throwIO` and may make things cleaner.

Comment: Hi I had the exact same confusion and just wanted to say that this answer really helped me a lot, thank you!